# How to optimize the following script

Tags: bash, scripting

This script runs a query to get a list of dates and runs two other queries for these dates. 
Then compares which one is the smaller of the numbers and multiplies it by 2.
Then writes to file and sums them.
Please suggest improvements. Also checks for 0 numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash

1>output.txt

today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
FirstOfTheMonth=$(date -d "--$(($(date +%-d)-1)) day" `enter code here`+"%Y%m%d")

 echo "XXXX activity report on daily and cumulative monthly `enter code here`basis "
 #query that outputs dates to a file
SQL query > list
#for each date I run 2 queries
for i in `cat list`;do
a1=SQL query;
b1=SQL query;
# I compare to find out which one is the smaller number and `enter code here`multiply it by 2

buy=${a1#-}
sell=${b1#-}
echo "XXX report for $yesterday  month = $i "

echo "Buy  $buy"
echo "Sell  $sell"

if [ "$buy" -lt "$sell" ];
then DayNumber=$[buy * 2];
else DayNumber=$[sell * 2];
fi;
#I write all the numbers to a file since I have to sum them
MonthNumber=`awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' `enter `enter code here`code here`DayNumber$i`
echo "Day Number $DayNumber"
echo "$DayNumber$i $MonthNumber$1 $yesterday" >> DayNumber$i

echo "Day Number since $FirstOfTheMonth $MonthNumber$1"
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
done
/usr/bin/mail -s "XXXX report $today" xxx@xxxx.com < `enter code here`output.txt
```

Comment: If the code works as you expect and you just want to improve, post it on [codereview.se].

Comment: Also, if you're talking performance optimizations, we'd want you to (1) specify very specifically what you want to be optimized, and remove all code unrelated to that thing; and (2) specify exactly which version of bash you're targeting (for date math, the big improvements in the bash interpreter itself -- potentially letting you stop using GNU date in favor of relying on builtins -- were released in 4.2).

Comment: Also, all the `enter code here` or `SQL query` placeholders mean that what you're posting here isn't a valid MCVE, since it isn't complete or verifiable; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: (and the `a1=SQL query` placeholder actually breaks your code, since it's running a command named `query` with `a1` exported to `SQL` for the duration of that single command... meaning that http://shellcheck.net/ correctly reports that `a1` isn't assigned later, because it'd need to be `a1="SQL query"` to be a valid assignment).

Comment: Will move this to Code Review. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting down votes, do to the size of the code, lack of clarity on what you want, not showing effort to get that result on your own, and very rudimentary mistakes in code readability that could be fixed with a web search for a tutorial.  Google has a shell style guide that you should read.

If you are redirecting stdout to a file, you are probably running autonomously.  Which means you should redirect stderr too.
`exec &>output.txt`

First of the month-- not sure why you don't just do this
`FirstOfTheMonth=$(date +%Y%m1)`

For Pete's sake, indent!  This makes me want to beat scripters.  Also, don't use i unless it's a very small loop.  Use a variable that means something.

```
while read -rd' ' month; do
   some commands
   if [[ $buy -lt $sell ]]; then
      do this thing here
   fi
done
```

Bash isn't semi-colon terminated, you don't need one at the end of a line.  Use the interan [[ ]] over the externam [ ].  Don't quote a variable (e.g. "$buy") to do a numeric comparison (e.g. -lt).  Keep your then on the same line as if-- it servers no other purpose than to make it more readable.